# Is occasional Invalid viewstate error Affect asp.net website performance?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, server, viewstate

I am seeing the

> Invalid viewstate

errors in my logs for an **ASP.NET** 3.5 application, is that effect my website performance?

on the following the Error:

> Stack Trace : The stack trace is unavailable.         Inner Exception
>         ---------------
>   Type : System.Web.HttpException, System.Web,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xx
>         Message : Invalid viewstate: Missing field: __VIEWSTATE4.       Source :
>   System.Web        Help link :         ErrorCode : -2147467259         Data :
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>   TargetSite : System.String
>   get_RequestViewStateString()      Stack Trace :    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.get_RequestViewStateString()

Is there away to handle this exception instead of see errors in logs?

Comment: Where in log? Did you write it or .net has?

Comment: it is famous error:Exception: System.Web.UI.ViewStateException
Message: Invalid viewstate. 
Client IP: 
Port: XX
User-Agent: T-Mobile Dash Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; 
Windows CE; Smartphone; 320x240)

Comment: @Imad .Net throw it, with no exception on ui ..it is very strange, i can not find a solution for it, it is throw error each 1 minute ..:(